# Java - double menuBar - set 'static' and 'void' parametr

Tags: java, reference, static, void

Problem is with:

1. paintUI()
   becouse cannot make a static reference to the non-static method paintUI() from the type Gui
2. exitb.addActionListener.

The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (new ActionListener(){})

How can i fix that?

```
//imports..

public class Gui extends JFrame 
{ 


public Gui() { 
    paintUI();
    }

    public final void paintUI() 
    {
        createToolBars();   
        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        //setting of 'f' ...  
    } 


    private void createToolBars() {

        JToolBar toolbar1 = new JToolBar();
        JToolBar toolbar2 = new JToolBar();

        ImageIcon newi = new ImageIcon("new.png");
        //another next icons..

        JButton newb = new JButton(newi);
        // another next jbuttons

        toolbar1.add(newb);
```

Here is a problem  with exitb.addActionListener becouse..:
Multiple markers at this line
    - ActionListener cannot be resolved to a type
    - The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type 
     AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (new ActionListener(){})

```
        exitb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        });
        createLayout(toolbar1, toolbar2);  
    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        //some creating....

        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[0], GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                 GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(arg[1], GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                 GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[0])
                .addComponent(arg[1])
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
```

/** 
Here is a problem  with reference of "paintUI()" becouse:
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method paintUI() from the type Gui
*/

```
                paintUI(); 
            }
        });
    }  
} }
```

Comment: Wow, that is a large example... please simplify it and create a minimal example to make it easier for us to provide feedback.

Comment: Try `Gui g = new Gui();`you cant invoke a non `static` method from a `static` one.

Comment: Don't use a null layout!!! Swing was designed to be used with layout managers for too many reasons to list here.

Answer (score 1):

```
paintUI();//here is a problem with reference
```

You have not created an instance of the Gui class so you can't invoke a method of the class.

Instead you should use:

```
new Gui();
```

You don't need to invoke paintUI() because your constructor of the Gui class will do this for you.

As the other answer shows the above statement should actually be invoked from within a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` because all GUI components should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). This is an important concept to understand.

Comment: True ture, @arkani be cautious with this though. Don't call anything from within the `constructor` that require the object to actually be already created .

Comment: @DimaMaligin, not sure I understand the point of this comment. The constructor is responsible for creating the GUI. Whether you create the components in the constructor or invoke a method from the constructor doesn't make any difference. The `paintUI()` method should be private and always invoked from the constructor.

Comment: @arkani, don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Ad.1. To call a non-static method from a static method you need to have a reference to an object. For example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Gui gui = new Gui();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                gui.paintUI();
            }
        });
    }
```